# NSStatusBar App - Window always on top (ignore hot corners)

Tags: objective-c, nsstatusbar, apple-expose, mission-control

I'm trying to replicate a behavior found in Evernote's NSStatusBar icon (see image).  I have my top left corner - hot corner set to show desktop.  This moves all windows away except the evernote menu.  How do they accomplish this?

I've tried all of the setLevel options. hideOnDeactive NO.

[image: Evernote ignores hot corners]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a simple one.  Check the Exposé setting in the Attributes Inspector of your xib file.

[image: This is what I was looking for]